# SSIS job hanging during data flow from SQL Server to Oracle database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, freeze

My SSIS package hangs during data flow from a SQL Server table into an Oracle database. Unfortunately, it's random - sometimes it works, but the times it does not it hangs at different points in execution.

The goal is to have the package complete without hanging.

Back in 2019 this package used to work without this problem. I've been pretty stumped on what the issue could be (network? driver? is there a workaround I could implement in the SSIS package?), and would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Description of the package and problem:

- **Purpose**: The purpose of the package is to load data from a **SQL Server** table to an **Oracle** table. It does this twice; first for a table with 350,000 records and then after for another table with 900,000 records.
- **Problem**: The random hanging problem occurs when I try to run it while deployed to SQL Server Agent on  our Windows server (Server 2008). When I run the job from my own local machine however, I do not get this hanging issue. When it hangs, it could have stopped around 200,000 records, 10,000, anywhere.
- When it hangs, nothing seems to happen. The job in SQL Server Agent shows itself as "Running" but data has stopped being loaded into the destination table. The job needs to be cancelled manually.
- When the job hangs, the last message in the execution report is always: **"Execute phase is beginning."**

Other information:

- Connection Manager Provider for the Oracle connection: **Native OLE DB\Oracle Provider for OLE DB**. It uses a tnsnames.ora for server info.
- Windows server version the package is deployed on: **Server 2008**
- TargetServerVersion: **SQL Server 2012**
- I have set **Delayed Validation** to **True** throughout the package's steps per suggestions I've seen on the web.
- I have also set **data access mode** for the package's Oracle OLE DB destinations to **SQL command**.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? YOu tell us that sometimes your SSIS package hangs, great, but what do you want us to do about it. What are you asking? SQL Server 2008 is completely unsupported, and the problem you;re having is on that instance, so upgrading seems like the right choice to start off with. YOu could also enable verbose logging in the package, which I *think* is available in the old package deployment method. SSISDB logs would tells you so much about what's going on; but that's only available in supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, thanks for your comment. I am trying to get the SSIS package to complete consistently, without the hanging issue that we've been getting. The package itself hasn't changed since this problem started occurring, so I am looking for ideas on solving this.

I am going to see if verbose logging is something I can enable, as well as if this package will perform better on our company's 2016 server which we are upgrading to (late, I know).